# Can I use a positional parameter in the FROM portion of my native query?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, db2

I am attempting to parameterize some SQL statements in my code in order to protect from SQL injection risks. My problem is that I am attempting to use the positional parameter in the FROM portion of my statement as opposed to the WHERE which is how I typically see it done.

Here's an example:

```java
 Query getNextContactIdQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT NEXTVAL FOR ? FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1.CNTCT_ID").setParameter(1, sequenceSchema);
```

The parameter is a schema that varies based on the environment the application is running in instead of an input variable that I typically see being used in these sorts of situations.

When I attempt to run the code with the parameter in it's current position I receive a `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement` error.

Comment: that syntax is only for parameters not for table names or columns for that matter

Comment: Positional parameters are used to apply scalar values. Use Dynamic SQL if you want to change other parts of the SQL statement.

Comment: @TheImpaler Pardon my ignorance, but do you have any resources showing how Dynamic SQL could help here? A few searches didn't net me anything helpful.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is essentially the old way of concatenating strings to assemble a running query. This is highly unsafe, of course, and can be susceptible of SQL Injection. On the other hand, you are trying to **apply** a parameter using the `?` syntax. This syntax is always safe, but it does not cover all possible cases. One of them is your case.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a possibility to make this case a real false positive by using concatenation. You need to produce a statement where the value is surrounded by double quotes. That is, produce this kind of statement:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR "variable part".CNTCT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

In this case DB2 is forced to consider the variable part as the schema name of the sequence.

This is provided that the value does not itself contain a double quote.

And this implies that the schema name value is now case sensitive.